# Preserve permissions files in sync cloud folder

Tags: permissions, files, executable

I use to work in two different computers. Some folders and files are synchronized on the cloud.

One folder contains scripts. Every time I use a script in one of the computers I need to change the executed permission of this file when I run it in the other.

Is there a way to set a configuration to keep all the files of that folder always as executable files regardless of which computer I am using.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on the software doing the synchronization to the "cloud".

Comment: I have the folders and files in Megasync.

Comment: https://github.com/megous/megatools/issues/11

Comment: tar preserves permissions. It is always cheaper to tar.gz files before transporting them anyways.

Comment: I guess the solution that @muru gives is the solution I am looking for. The issue is that I am not sure how to configure it. In my case I have a local folder ~/mega that is synchronized in Mega by Megasync. Does that solution require of another intermediate folder? Perhaps one solution could be to code a script in crontab to make all those scripts executable in that session? I would like you to propose some ideas that they work for you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After surfing the net, the most suitable solution fits to me is to write a script which runs at the beginning of each session with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Destination directory
cd ~/bin

# Set all the files as executable
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 775
```

In this way every time I start a session on any of my two computers, all the files located in the ~/bin directory are executable in this session.